# Symfony2 Custom Query Only Returning 1 Record, Should Return Multiple

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a 3 tables that I am joining together, "PurchaseOrderProductsStatus, Product and PutAway" tables.

PurchaseOrderProductsStatus Table

```
id  | product_id | 
----------------------
10  | 1      |
```

Product Table

```
id  | Name            | 
---------------------------
1   | Acme Product 123
```

PutAway Table

```
id  | product_id | 
----------------------
100 | 1
101 | 1
```

I am able to output the data to the screen, the issue I am running into is that it is only returning 1 row from my PutAway table. It should return 2 rows like so...

```
Acme Product 123
        100 - Acme Product 123
        101 - Acme Product 123
```

Here is my customQuery. What Am I doing wrong?

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
->createQuery('
SELECT      pops, pr, pa
FROM        WIC\PurchaseOrderBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrderProductsStatus pops
LEFT JOIN   pops.product pr
LEFT JOIN   pr.putAway pa
WHERE       pops.inventoryLocation = :id
AND         pops.account = :account_id
')
->setParameter('id', $id)
->setParameter('account_id', $account_id);
```

Just a bit of information on my set up. In my Product Entity I have a oneToMany Association for the PutAway table.

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="WIC\InventoryBundle\Entity\PutAway", mappedBy="product", fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $putAway;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->putAway = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Here is my twig template:

```
{% for action in productActions %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ action.product.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ action.product.sku }}</td>
        <td>{{ action.product.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ action.qty }}</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span2">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Purchase Order</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="span10">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="put_away_{{ action.product.id }}">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Put Away Location</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Entered By</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {% for putAway in action.product.putAway %}
                            <tr class="info">
                                <td>{{ putAway.inventoryLocation.name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ putAway.qty }}</td>
                                <td>{{ putAway.created|date("m/d/Y") }}</td>
                                <td>{{ putAway.createdBy.firstName }} {{ putAway.createdBy.lastName }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you update the question with `PutAway#product` property? What `@JoinColumn` did you define there? Also, check the dev toolbar to see which query in being executed and try running it directly from `SQL` console...

Comment: Forgive my ignorance I dont know what this means "Can you update the question with PutAway#product property". I am new to Symfony.

Comment: It's ok, I will continue writing as "asnwer" due to better formatting capability ;)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have defined the following relation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="WIC\InventoryBundle\Entity\PutAway", mappedBy="product",     fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $putAway;
```

The `mappedBy="product"` tells me that `PutAway` entity has the `product` property - probably defined as `@ManyToOne` (the opposite).

As you may know, in relations if you omit the `@JoinColumn` (or `@JoinTable` for many-to-many) `Doctrine` will assume the default column names and try to join the tables. However, this may produce the unexpected results (such as yours).

Now the important part: If you want to ensure the correct columns are being used you need to set `@JoinColumn` annotation on one side of relation. In your example:

**<kbd>Product entity</kbd>**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="WIC\InventoryBundle\Entity\PutAway", mappedBy="product",     fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id_product")
 */
protected $putAway;
```

The alternate solution would be:

**<kbd>PutAway entity</kbd>**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\InventoryBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="putAway", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_product", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $product;
```

In `@JoinColumn` annotation:

- `name` represents the local (hm, some better term maybe) column
- `referencedColumnName` represents the foreign column

Will this work?

Comment: Yeah this just does the same thing that I already have in place. I am still only getting one "PutAway" record to return instead of both "PutAway" records. I just dont know why it will only return 1 and not both of them. I added your line "* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id_product")" to the Product Entity, but no change in the number of results returned.

Comment: Weird. Ok, try clicking on "Queries" in your debug toolbar. That should give you all the executed queries. Find this one add it to your question ;)